# executing bash commands from a specific directory

Tags: java, bash, jar, execute

From my application I have to execute an external jar of which I do not have the source.
Given an input file, it processes it, creates an "output" directory and puts in it an mxml output file. Problem is: it creates said directory in tomcat/bin instead of inside the directory of the original file.

Here's what I've tried so far.
Initially

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("java -jar "+newfile.getParent()+"\\converter.jar "+newfile.getPath()+" -mxml").start();
```

Then, seeing how from console the "output" directory was created in the directory the command was called from, I tried:

```
String startSim[] = {"cd "+newfile.getParent()+"\\" , "java -jar converter.jar "+newfile.getName()+" -mxml"};

try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(startSim).waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Log non creato.");
}
```

But with this I get the "file not found" exception for the first instruction. Does anyone know how to possibly solve this problem? I'd like to avoid having to reach for my output file all the way in my tomcat/bin directory.

Thanks for any suggestion!
Paolo

P.s.: by the way, before trying all this I tried simply calling the method I need from the library, but had the same exact problem. So I resolved to execute the jar, instead. And here we are. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set working directory using `ProcessBuilder.directory()` method:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.directory(new File("mydirectory"));
pb.command(......);
```

etc

This does not work for you when  you are using `Runtime.exec()` because `cd` command is a functionality of shell. You could solve it using this technique but you have to create platform specific command with prefix like `cmd /c` on windows or `/bin/sh` on Linux. This way is definitely not recommended.

But in your specific case you do not neither first nor second solution. Actually you are starting one java process from another. Why? you can easily invoke the `main()` method of the second process directly.

Take a look on `META-INF/MANIFEST.mf` file from `converter.jar`. Field `Main-Class` contains the fully qualified name of main class. Let's say it is `com.converters.Main` (just for example). In this case you can invoke

```
com.converters.Main.main(new String[] {newFile.getPath(), "-mxml"});
```

directly from your code. Just add the jar to your classpath.

Concerning to changing working directory in this case. Check again whether you really need this or your converters.jar supports parameter that does this.

Comment: Alas, as far as my decompiling suggest, the output directory is statically determined. I had actually already tried calling the main ma+ethod, with the same problem.
I've been trying to use your suggestion to set a working directory for my process, but it keeps generating a "java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)" exception, so I'm a little stuck.
If you have other suggestions you are really more than welcome. In the meantime, I'll keep trying...

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Ok, I was actually able to solve thanks to your suggestion. At first it didn't work because I kept using `newfile.getName()` as string values in my array. Apparently, that was unwelcome. As soon as I switched to spelling out filenames, it worked.

Comment: Errata corrige: the problem was probably elsewere in the syntax, probably some extra space somewhere... something like " -mxml" instead of "-mxml".

Answer (score 0):

A lazy approach to this may be going to the root directory and descending from there to your tomcat bin directory .

Comment: That would be possibile, but it's exactly what I'd like to avoid... ^_^"
Thanks anyway!